# Alternative to FTP server for online storage of big files

Tags: storage, google-drive, cloud-storage

I'm offering my software to be downloaded from my website.
My setup files are huge, so I've rented a separate webserver just for storing these file. I pay like 30 € / year.
This is not much, but the server is located in Germany, and sometimes the connection for people in other countries is not ideal.

I was therefore asking myself if Google perhaps offers such a service as well. I guess Google has an excellent connection for everyone without any bandwidth or connection problems.

Unfortunately Google Drive doesn't offer direct downloads, so it would look unprofessional if I point to a Google drive.

Does anybody know a fast and relatively cheap alternative to my country-based web server?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each file that you put in *Dropbox* (even with a free account) can have a **shared link** that you can give to your customers, .

Check the section `Create a shared link` in this [tutorial](https://www.dropbox.com/help/167).